# Rewrite date function from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ function like

```
string LocalDate()
{
  time_t current = time(NULL);
  struct tm *local_time = localtime(&current);
  char TIME[0xFF] ;
  sprintf(TIME, "%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", local_time->tm_year % 100, local_time->tm_mon + 1,
  local_time->tm_mday, local_time->tm_hour, local_time->tm_min, local_time->tm_sec);
  return string(TIME);
}
```

Which I rewrote to C# like this

```
public static string LocalDate()
{
    DateTime value = DateTime.Now;
    return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", value.Year.ToString("00"),
                                               value.Month.ToString("00"), value.Day.ToString("00"),
                                               value.Hour.ToString("00"), value.Minute.ToString("00"), value.Second.ToString("00"));
}
```

The only different being C# returns `20151029155030`. While C++ returns `151029155030`. **(Year part in C++ has value 115 actually - the structure I mean)**

You can see C++ omits 20 of the year part. My first question is doesn't C++ part seem weird to you? How will it correctly calculate years say in 2212? (Will not it be same as 2112? etc.)

How to make C# output same value do %100?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")` ?

Comment: Well, I would expect `local_time->tm_year % 100` to produce no more than two digits.  :-)  I believe you instead should add the base year (epoch) of 1900 to get the current year.

Comment: The C++ part omits the 20 part because you do `local_time->tm_year % 100`. Then of course, 2212 and 2112 will give the same value!

Comment: Converting **famously buggy** code from C++ to C# isn't a good idea. I thought we got rid of the Y2K bug 15 years ago!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you please explain what do you mean? Indeed this C++ software could have been written like 10 years ago

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, next bug is expected to happens in 85 years, until then I am also planning to store years as 2 digits only, I'll probably be well dead when my co-workers will discover it ;)

Comment: The [Y2K bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)! Come on!!!! Billions were spent right up to December 31, 1999 to *fix* such code! Newscasters worried that even coffee makers would stop working! Sean Connery and Catherine Zeta Jones took advantage of the bug in [Entrapment](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137494/) to steal 8 bn!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you explain in simple terms :) ? Also do you have idea why this code would use custom structures such as this? `typedef struct tag_dppDatetime_t
{
    WORD    Year;    // Year (1900..2100)
    WORD    Month;   // Month (1..12)
    WORD    Day;     // Day (1..31)
    WORD    Hour;    // Hour (0..23)
    WORD    Minute;  // Minutes (0..59)
    WORD    Second;  // Seconds (0..59)
} dppDatetime_t ;
` ??

Comment: @Sinatr seeing how such things tend to happen next Tuesday, I wouldn't repeat what you typed. All you need is having to store a 90s date somewhere and forget about it. In fact, you have to put effort in modern databases and languages to store two-digit years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: How can you deduce there is 100% there bug? and how do you recommend to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a [Custom DateTime format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss");
```

The problem with your implementation is that `value.Year.ToString("00")` does not limit the string to two digits.  That only makes sure that the `string` will have at least 2 digits and left pad with zeros if there are less.  To replicate the C++ could you could have done `value.Year % 100` instead.

Comment: "does not limit the string to two digits" how to limit string to 2 digits? Another function might be doing similar as this one but from Custom date structure, so I need to know how to limit to two digits too

Comment: can you deduce there is 100% that Y2K bug? and how do you recommend to fix that?

Comment: @Quser If you are worried about the fact that you only capture the last two digits of the year the fix would of course be to include all 4 digits.  With that said two digits only really becomes an issue if you work with dates that can span more than 100 years.  If you know all dates you work with will never be in the future and never more than say 20 years in the past then deducing the correct century is easy.  Also I included how to limit the year to two digits by using `%100` just like in the C++ code.

Comment: " if you work with dates that can span more than 100 years. If you know all dates you work with will never be in the future and never more than say 20 years in the past then deducing the correct century is easy" - If you elaborate on this I will appreciate, I didn't really get it. I think I should raise this issue with my colleagues too?

Comment: If all your dates are not in the future and no more than 20 years in the past then you should know that 0-15 is 2000 - 2015 and 95-99 are 1995 - 1999.  Anything else would be invalid.  Basically you can use the current date to determine what the century should be.  It really depends on what type of dates you are working with.  But honestly it's usually better to just use all 4 digits if possible.

Comment: I guess it is better also to inform my colleagues

Comment: Do you know why author would need custom Date structures like this? `typedef struct tag_dppDatetime_t { WORD Year; // Year (1900..2100) WORD Month; // Month (1..12) WORD Day; // Day (1..31) WORD Hour; // Hour (0..23) WORD Minute; // Minutes (0..59) WORD Second; // Seconds (0..59) } dppDatetime_t ;`

Comment: Nope, I've done very little C++ coding so I think that's better asked to someone with more knowledge in C++ than I.

Comment: Ok but at least I think I should notify my colleagues

Answer (score 0):

> (Year part in C++ has value 115 actually - the structure I mean)
>
> You can see C++ omits 20 of the year part. My first question is doesn't C++ part seem weird to you? How will it correctly calculate years say in 2212? (Will not it be same as 2112? etc.

DateTime has as year value the years since 0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year%28v=vs.110%29.aspx